# UTF8String produces literal pound symbol ¬£ objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, utf-8

For some reason when I try to print out a currency symbol into a pdf document in my iPhone app I cam getting ¬£ printed instead of £. (The pound symbol is used when the iPhone is set to UK settings).

This is my code:

```
text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Helper convertDoubleToCurrencyString:[item.Total floatValue]]]; 
                                            WriteOutTextInPDF(pdfContext, [text UTF8String], priceX, currentY, 16);

+(NSString*) convertDoubleToCurrencyString:(double) d{
    NSDecimalNumber *decimal = (NSDecimalNumber*)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:d];
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    return [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:decimal];
}

void WriteOutTextInPDF(CGContextRef pdfContext, const char *text, int x, int y, int fontSize){
    CGContextSelectFont (pdfContext, "Helvetica", fontSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (pdfContext, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (pdfContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint (pdfContext, x, y, text, strlen(text));
}
```

Any ideas how I get the symbol instead of this representation?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UTF-8 text, the character £ is represented by the two bytes `0xc2 0xa3`. But in the [Mac Roman encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman), those two bytes represent the two characters ¬ and £.

You could use `[text cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding]` instead of `[text UTF8String]` to convert the string using the encoding CGGraphics expects. Or you could try using `UIGraphicsPushContext` and the [UIKit string drawing functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aconstrainedToSize%3alineBreakMode%3a) to draw the string with UIKit, which may support UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks. That explains that. I noticed the two bytes but had no idea to write out the Mac Roman representation of them.